# Change visible url but keep old redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have static webpage. It contains 3 languages. Every language is separate folder. So I have folder eng, de and hr. In each folder I have index.php, exapmle1.php, example2.php etc. I have .htaccess in which I have :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase  /
redirect 301 /index.php http://www.example.com/eng/
```

So what I need is that I remove folder when I enter it.
I have:

```
  http://www.example.com/eng/index.php
```

or

```
 http://www.example.com/de/index.php
```

and I need:

```
  http://www.example.com/index.php
```

I tried to remove eng but I need to be able to enter another folder when I click on language chooser.

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+eng/([^\s]+) [NC]
```

Can someone give me some hint ?

EDIT:

so now I have url:

```
example.com/hr/index.php
example.com/eng/index.php
example.com/de/index.php
example.com/hr/aboutus.php
example.com/eng/aboutus.php
example.com/de/aboutus.php
```

so you can guess that I have 3 folders in my file structure. I have eng, de and hr folders and inside them I have files called index.php and aboutus.php.

I have html 'a' elements that leads to files like hr/index.php, eng/aboutus.php etc.

I need to change url and it should be displayed like:

```
  example.com/hr/index.php
```

to

```
  example.com/naslovna


  example.com/eng/index.php
```

to

```
  example.com/home

  example.com/eng/aboutus.php
```

to

```
  example.com/aboutus
```

Comment: Sorry for little complication :)
I have example.com/eng/index.php, example.com/eng/page1.php etc
I need to change url to example.com/great-page, example.com/nice-rooms etc. But I need to keep links to leed to eng/index.php etc.
Did I explain it clearly ?

Comment: No, you did not really explain it clearly. Simply tell us: 1. visible URL should X, 2. file displayed should be Y, and give us a number of examples.

Comment: Is this clear now or should I give more examples ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I figured out that this works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^page-name/?$   index.php?page=page-name
```